# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

Tags: mysql

I need some help below, I am getting this error please help me with the solution.

SQL query:

```
===EMPLOYEE===

------- Table Structure For Job Seeker----------

CREATE TABLE `employees`(

  `ee_id` int(4) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `ee_email` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `ee_password` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `ee_fname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `ee_lname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `ee_day` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `ee_month` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `ee_year` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `ee_gender` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 
  `ee_address` varchar(256) NOT NULL, /*Address newly added.*/
 
  `ee_country` varchar(130) NOT NULL,
  `ee_city` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `ee_education` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `ee_master` varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
  `ee_mcode` varchar(10) NOT NULL,  
  `ee_mnumber` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `ee_experience` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `ee_skills` varchar(130) NOT NULL,
  `ee_industry` varchar(130) NOT NULL,
  `ee_certification` varchar(130) NOT NU[...]
```

Below is what I am getting as an error:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near
> '======================================EMPLOYEE==================================' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

You can't just lob text with `=` wherever you please in your script. Comments need to start with two dashes (`--`). So you could, for instance, have you file's header as so:

```
--- Employee ---
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, your suggestion has corrected the error.